# How can i draw this shape using rounded rectangle tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing, line-art, distort

[image]

Hi,
i want to draw this shape but using rounded rectangle tool. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Draw the rounded rectangle then choose `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Warp > Inflate`

[image]

To get it back to a standard path afterwards, choose `Object > Expand` from the menu.

Comment: You are awesome Scott!

Comment: @user1942224 Glad this helped. Don't forget to click the "answered' checkmark on the left if this solved your issue.